# Rails - Use self column in sql string query in concern scope

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, geocoding

So, I have this concern and scope

```
module GeocoordinatesHelpers
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern

  included do
    scope :within_range, -> (lat, lon, range) { where("(6371.0 * 2 * ASIN(SQRT(POWER(SIN((self.latitude - :lat) * PI() / 180 / 2), 2) + COS(self.latitude * PI() / 180) * COS(:lat * PI() / 180) * POWER(SIN((self.longitude - :lon) * PI() / 180 / 2), 2)))) <= :range", {lat: lat, lon: lon, range: range})}
  end
end
```

that I need to use across several models

Is it possible to refer to the models column that the scope is being called against? Like, replace the `self` bits in the where with something that actually works

For reasons, I can't just use the geocoder gem

Comment: in this case `self` will be the class you'll include the module into

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you really need the full column name, try changing `self` to `#{table_name}`.

Comment: `${table_name}`? global variable? and why would this be of any use?

Comment: `#{table_name}` will be called in the scope of the included class. Ops.. There's a typo there.

Comment: Perfect, that's exactly what I was looking for, thank you